# click event getElementByClassName returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my HTML code:

```
<div id="right">
    <div class="beschrijving">1</div>
    <div class="beschrijving">2</div>
    <div class="beschrijving">3</div>
    <div class="beschrijving">4</div>
    <div class="beschrijving">5</div>
    <div class="beschrijving">6</div>
</div>
```

This div is on the right side of my page; on the left side are 6 images with the `class:portfolio-item` (I am making a portfolio). The divs with the class `beschrijving` (which means description) is `block: none;` in CSS.

```
<div id="left">
    <div class="portfolio-item">
        <img src="images/fuxing.jpg" alt="fuxing"/>
        <div class="label">
            <h2>Fuxing</h2>
            <p>gebouwd met: HTML5, CSS, jQuery<br /> Responsive: yes<br />Gemaakt in 2013</p>
            <a href="fuxing/index.html">bekijk website</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is: if I click on one of the images, the description of its image must be shown on the page. For example: 3e image shows the 3e description, but the JavaScript code returns an empty value.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var img = document.getElementsByClassName("portfolio-item"),
                text = document.getElementsByClassName("beschrijving"), i;
        for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
            img[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                text[i].style.display = "block";
            }, false);
        }
    }, false);
}());
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Yes, @Lal, it is. Not particularly readable (in my opinion) but valid

Comment: the html of the portfolio-item seems to be missing? I'm sure your text has the correct array of items :)

Comment: @Lal, he is iterating the images for portfolio-item just there is none in the shown html example

Comment: @Icepickle. Yes the text is correct. is just like:
<div id="left">
     
      <div class="portfolio-item">
       <img src="images/fuxing.jpg" alt="fuxing"/>
       <div class="label">
        <h2>Fuxing</h2>
        <p>gebouwd met: HTML5, CSS, jQuery<br /> Responsive: yes<br />Gemaakt in 2013</p>
        <a href="fuxing/index.html">bekijk website</a>
       </div>
      </div>
</div>

Comment: Please add all relevant information (including the code above) to your question using the **edit** link under the question

Comment: i just showed the code of 1 of the six images...i hope you dont get confused :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the scoped variable i is at the time of execution, outside of the index of the array.

Easier said, the click function only gets executed once the image gets clicked, at that time, the i in scope has your text.length + 1

You have to either extract the function from your for so you use a new variable to point to the scope, or bind the callback function with the current index

So, change to this

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("portfolio-item"), text = document.getElementsByClassName("beschrijving"), i;
for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].addEventListener("click", function (localindex) {
        text[localindex].style.display = "block";
    }.bind(img[i], i), false);
}
```

or make it like this

```
function clickHandlerImages(index) { 
     text[index].style.display = "block";
}

var img = document.getElementsByClassName("portfolio-item"), text = document.getElementsByClassName("beschrijving"), i;
for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].addEventListener("click", clickHandlerImages.bind(img[i], i), false);
}
```

or by using

```
function setClickHandler(img, text) {
    img.addEventListener("click", function() {
        text.style.display = "block";
    }, false);
}

var img = document.getElementsByClassName("portfolio-item"), text = document.getElementsByClassName("beschrijving"), i;
for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    setClickHandler(img[i], text[i]);
}
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var arrPortfolioItems = document.getElementsByClassName('portfolio-item'),
      arrDescriptionItems = document.getElementsByClassName('beschrijving'),
      i, len, portfolioItem, descriptionItem, currentIndex;
  
  for (i = 0, len = arrPortfolioItems.length; i < len; i++) {
    portfolioItem = arrPortfolioItems[i];
    descriptionItem = arrDescriptionItems[i];
    
    portfolioItem.addEventListener('click', function(localIndex) {
      if (currentIndex !== localIndex) {
        // reset the previously selected
        if (typeof currentIndex !== 'undefined') {
          arrDescriptionItems[currentIndex].style.display = 'none';
        }
        currentIndex = localIndex;
        arrDescriptionItems[currentIndex].style.display = 'block';
      }
    }.bind(portfolioItem, i));
  }
});
```

```css
.beschrijving {
  display: none;
}
#left
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 200px;
}
#right
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <div class="portfolio-item">
    <img src="images/fuxing.jpg" alt="fuxing" />
    <div class="label">
      <h2>Fuxing</h2>
      <p>gebouwd met: HTML5, CSS, jQuery
        <br />Responsive: yes
        <br />Gemaakt in 2013</p>
      <a href="fuxing/index.html">bekijk website</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-item">
    <img src="images/fuxing.jpg" alt="fuxing" />
    <div class="label">
      <h2>Fuxing</h2>
      <p>gebouwd met: HTML5, CSS, jQuery
        <br />Responsive: yes
        <br />Gemaakt in 2013</p>
      <a href="fuxing/index.html">bekijk website</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-item">
    <img src="images/fuxing.jpg" alt="fuxing" />
    <div class="label">
      <h2>Fuxing</h2>
      <p>gebouwd met: HTML5, CSS, jQuery
        <br />Responsive: yes
        <br />Gemaakt in 2013</p>
      <a href="fuxing/index.html">bekijk website</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-item">
    <img src="images/fuxing.jpg" alt="fuxing" />
    <div class="label">
      <h2>Fuxing</h2>
      <p>gebouwd met: HTML5, CSS, jQuery
        <br />Responsive: yes
        <br />Gemaakt in 2013</p>
      <a href="fuxing/index.html">bekijk website</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-item">
    <img src="images/fuxing.jpg" alt="fuxing" />
    <div class="label">
      <h2>Fuxing</h2>
      <p>gebouwd met: HTML5, CSS, jQuery
        <br />Responsive: yes
        <br />Gemaakt in 2013</p>
      <a href="fuxing/index.html">bekijk website</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-item">
    <img src="images/fuxing.jpg" alt="fuxing" />
    <div class="label">
      <h2>Fuxing</h2>
      <p>gebouwd met: HTML5, CSS, jQuery
        <br />Responsive: yes
        <br />Gemaakt in 2013</p>
      <a href="fuxing/index.html">bekijk website</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="right">
  <div class="beschrijving">1</div>
  <div class="beschrijving">2</div>
  <div class="beschrijving">3</div>
  <div class="beschrijving">4</div>
  <div class="beschrijving">5</div>
  <div class="beschrijving">6</div>
</div>
```

I added a snippet to show how the code could be written to work, I was a bit lazy, so all the portfolio items are the same, but the descriptions should be shown and hidden as you click the different portfolio items

Comment: great, but it only fires once.. if i click on the another image, the description wont change.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, it changes...but only from a higher value to a lower one...example: if ik click on image 5 and then on 3, the description changes. but from 3 to 5 does not work..

Comment: @FFBbodie probably because you didn't hide the previously displayed description, but i added a snippet to show you how you could do it